# Verify Cyclic Difference Sets

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, number-theory

A cyclic [difference set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_set) is a set of positive integers with a unique property:

1. Let `n` be the largest integer in the set.
2. Let `r` be any integer (not necessarily in the set) greater than 0 but less than or equal to `n/2`.
3. Let `k` be the *number of solutions* to `(b - a) % n = r` where `a` and `b` are any members of the set.  Each solution is an ordered pair `(a,b)`.  (Also note that this version of modulo makes negative numbers positive by adding `n` to it, unlike the implementations in many languages.)
4. Finally, if and only if this is a cyclic difference set, the value of `k` does not depend on your choice of `r`.  That is, all values of `r` give the same number of solutions to the above congruence.

This can be illustrated with the following example:

```
Cyclic difference set: {4,5,6,8,9,11}
0 < r <= 11/2, so r = 1,2,3,4,5
r=1: (4,5) (5,6) (8,9)
r=2: (4,6) (6,8) (9,11)
r=3: (5,8) (6,9) (8,11)
r=4: (4,8) (5,9) (11,4)  since (4-11)%11=(-7)%11=4
r=5: (4,9) (6,11) (11,5)
```

Each value of `r` has the same number of solutions, 3 in this case, so this is a cyclic difference set.

### Input

Input will be a list of positive integers.  Since this is a set property,  assume that input is *not* sorted.  You can assume that `n` is at least `2`, although `k` may be zero.

### Output

Your program/function should output a truthy value if the set is a cyclic difference set, or a falsey value otherwise.

### Test Cases

Valid cyclic difference sets:

```
10,12,17,18,21
7,5,4
57,1,5,7,17,35,38,49
1,24,35,38,40,53,86,108,114,118,135,144,185,210,254,266,273
16,3,19,4,8,10,15,5,6
8,23,11,12,15,2,3,5,7,17,1
```

([data source](https://www.ccrwest.org/diffsets.html), although their convention is different)

Invalid cyclic difference sets:

```
1,2,3,4,20
57,3,5,7,17,35,38,49
3,4,5,9
14,10,8
```

Comment: Can `a` and `b` be the same member (not necessarily `a ≠ b`)?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer if `b` and `a` are the same number, then `(b-a)%n = 0`, but 0 isn't one of the values that you're looking for solutions for.  So there's not an explicit prohibition on them being the same number, but they never will be.

Comment: Please add `14,10,8` to the list of non difference sets (to catch programs that ignore `0` counts)

Comment: I'd really prefer it if `7 7 7` was invalid input. A set doesn't repeat values

Comment: @TonHospel Done and done.  `7 7 7` was a requested by another user, but I've removed it because it is not a set.

Comment: Golfing idea: we don't need to bound `r` by `0 < r <= max(input)/2`, but instead `0 < r < max(input)` because we can obtain `r > max(input)/2` cases by simply flipping the subtraction in `r <= max(input)/2` cases.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 7 bytes

```
_þ%ṀṬSE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY6xEcIwDEV7pkhD9wvLtmxnAI4BKH05KhouC9BxNCyTBdLQZJKwiPlOCBV31lnS/5Le9dL3t1LO02s/j/d5HE6HMj3fj4HvWErOWQzEQiIkwUqHXdPkCIVfU6XAKlaHU7gE366KwPqtZaAOKUBMgohn8KcmnnlSLjaw6mFDgI3uuyDAQVp40EwK5Z2wSkShJAsZp@n7IiyANXK9zz53mh@p@09aXYoN29djiUXXfQA)

#### How it works

```
_þ%ṀṬSE  Main link. Argument: A (array of unique elements / ordered set)

_þ       Subtract table; yield a 2D array of all possible differences of two
         (not necessarily distinct) elements of A.
  %Ṁ     Take the differences modulo max(A).
    Ṭ    Untruth; map each array of differences modulo max(A) to a Boolean array
         with 1's at the specified indices. Note that all 0's in the index array
         are ignored, since indexing is 1-based in Jelly.
     S   Take the sum of these arrays, counting occurrences.
      E  Test if all resulting counts are equal.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
Ë#m%▲¹×-¹¹ḣ½▲
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU4xCgIxEOx9hSCCwgjZZJPLveWwF8TGwwdoa68P8AcW4hU2uZfoR@LE085i2d2Z3ZlZ7dp1Hm9m7euw387TLffHyWb6Ol1T158XqUvd835JDwI550bhERBRQ2Q5asRALKSCRNgCVOSV3RPiWBXOebgIrcs9rP52A@8QA8REiimLnZwo5@ipZ2C9woYAW7nyHeAgNZQBirMvYYjTm7h8ovCPR19nGSwJUMYMsdyfWIX3@ATUohyXbw)

The three superscript 1s seem wasteful...

### Explanation

```
Ë#m%▲¹×-¹¹ḣ½▲  Input is a list, say x=[7,5,4]
            ▲  Maximum: 7
           ½   Halve: 3.5
          ḣ    Inclusive range from 1: [1,2,3]
Ë              All elements are equal under this function:
                Argument is a number, say n=2.
      ×-¹¹      Differences of all pairs from x: [0,-2,2,-3,0,3,-1,1,0]
  m%▲¹          Map modulo max(x): [0,5,2,4,0,3,6,1,0]
 #              Count occurrences of n: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>86</s> <s>84</s> 81 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thaks to JungHwan Min</sup>

```python
lambda x:len({*map([(b-a)%max(x)for a in x for b in x].count,range(1,max(x)))})<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLboMwELz7K7hUMdW0Yv0AUjVfQjmYNiRIvEQciajqt9M1JIdKlWV5NDO7O97x5s9Dr5f68LG0rqu@XDS/tcdefj93bpSFrF5c/NS5Wc5xPUyRi5o@mqMAqxWWr5/DtfeYXH86SsJmjeOf@F0tfrr68@1QiIISkAJloByKSogig4UJwDLJOAuqttA5zD7wBGUeRAKrkaegJAeR4csva2QY55ZbJlDWQKUpVKbX8hQatIcBW3m65RlpEDgAC7Tm4Up23YffY/EpRSlq11626KuHeyf3tPq/tMFhEWApxDg1vZe77fs7tM3Fy7DOGhvF@3l41jF/LCvDjuUX)

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
SameQ@@Counts@Mod[#-#2&@@@#~Permutations~{2},Max@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LasMwELzrNwyhLVPqXT0sUwoLPQdSeiw9iMahOdiGRIGCcX7dXQX3VoSk0cysZvqUv7s@5eNXWg4vd8t76rs3kdfxMuSzbMf9R/VY8UZEquuuO/WXrN5xOF8nnrFNP1J9bpb7Z7M7HYcsD4cnmczk4BEQ0YJohpkafbsCfANSrGcD62EjXFt4Ars/ooa3iAFURx13uvVWjZzi6MFUg70DhwBu7G08wIJaOM1UlXzJL0IEq0AgLiSraw1fa@lScMtXTf@s15b2v5bF4dHOxszLLw)

Note, we don't need to divide the max element by two due to symmetry (we may check counts of all modulos `1` to `max(input) - 1`).

#### Explanation

```
#~Permutations~{2}
```

Take all length-2 permutations of the input.

```
#-#2&@@@
```

Find differences of each

```
Mod[ ... ,Max@#]
```

Mod the result by the maximal element of the input.

```
Counts@
```

Find the frequencies of each element.

```
SameQ@@
```

Return whether all of the numbers are the same.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

Returns **0** or **1**.

```js
a=>a.map(b=>a.map(c=>x[c=(c-b+(n=Math.max(...a)))%n-1]=-~x[c]),x=[])|!x.some(v=>v^x[0])
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>a.map(b=>a.map(c=>x[c=(c-b+(n=Math.max(...a)))%n-1]=-~x[c]),x=[])|!x.some(v=>v^x[0])

console.log('[Truthy]')
console.log(f([10,12,17,18,21]))
console.log(f([7,5,4]))
console.log(f([57,1,5,7,17,35,38,49]))
console.log(f([1,24,35,38,40,53,86,108,114,118,135,144,185,210,254,266,273]))
console.log(f([16,3,19,4,8,10,15,5,6]))
console.log(f([8,23,11,12,15,2,3,5,7,17,1]))

console.log('[Falsy]')
console.log(f([1,2,3,4,20]))
console.log(f([57,3,5,7,17,35,38,49]))
console.log(f([3,4,5,9]))
console.log(f([14,10,8]))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>68</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

Includes `+2` for `ap`

```
perl -apE '\@G[@F];pop@G;s:\d+:$G[$_-$&].=1for@F:eg;$_="@G"=~/^1*( 1*)\1*$/' <<< "4 5 6 8 9 11"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 74 bytes

```python
lambda x:len({sum(1+(a+r)%max(x)in x for a in x)for r in range(max(x))})<3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVC7bsMwDJzjr9BSQEJuMPWwFaP9EsWDisZtgNgJHBdwUfTbXTJOOnUgdOSdjgdevqaP8@CWTr2o/XLK/etbVnNzOgz6@/rZa9rqvB3NU59nPZvjoGbVnUeVlUAjcBQ45uH9oFeR@THPbMjUJNS@SClRCbKgGhRhqUWhVKoR4FcYmOCuFoULcBF@tzIE6x@jEsEhVqAygshz8cscecYxsHEJGzxsVcHW7m5QwYF28GAxpwi8p1opjsIU3ZLxb9bdI9wCSiXZz3P2LP@Suv@TiirgEdvLsshN2zbFRo4xyzGmRl3G4zDpTg5VbNbGLL8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 81 bytes

```ruby
->s{n=s.max
(1..n/2).map{|r|s.permutation(2).count{|a,b|(b-a)%n==r}}.uniq.size<2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9NboMwEIX3PoUVqRKRJi42Nhip9CKIBSREYRFDsZHaYs5Ox5B01U0XlufNm59vxqn5Wq/Fenq3syksu9efJOKMmVdxRDHMfvSWDe14n1ztut5EmD/3k3Gzr6HxUXOqjy@mKMZlYZPpPpjtvts3saxlKUFBChpy4LwCQkseAxfAM@AaxJ7KsEZukcI0iiz4iYJEg8z3LhDymYlBJaBT4LHGoRIf/uhxibFWODUGoSSINAWRJXt/CgnwHCSiBAIVsDYHKdDhGxT2YtljP69Ixdr6fKOXnnrbOk8oHcbOOHotUVa/8kAPpDUXQobJWULKQItzkCB@XpX8eVWoUfC4UAYw/d@l6/oD)

Ungolfed:

```ruby
->s{
  n=s.max
  (1..n/2).map{|r|               # For each choice of r
    s.permutation(2).count{|a,b| # Count the element pairs
      (b-a)%n==r                 #   for which this equality holds
    }
  }.uniq.size<2                  # All counts should be identical.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 84 bytes

```
l s=all((g 1==).g)[1..t-1]where t=maximum s;g j=[1|x<-s>>=(`map`s).(-),x==j||x+t==j]
```

l is the function that does the check. It just computes all differences and counts.

Comment: `let` in a pattern guard instead of `where` saves a byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcmxDoIwEADQ3a@4waGNR@OBBIweP0Ka0ESCYIvE1qRD/73q6PSGdzf@MVqbswWf7BggsDNxdm8H/jLBwj2leC1817EYnNkGL5UoJEbmJaV4CF81G2uFmICYpZpkT0qFgnR2Zl6B4fbcwfaa1wB7sNDTEalEapBaLEn/Xd1ghTU2v65qrFo8nXX@AA "Haskell – Try It Online")